# In Node.js does it matter if I write my objects' properties' objects even if they have a single property

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance

I'm new to the Javascript and Node.js so I'm sorry if I'm using wrong jargon, I was writing a schema, the reason I want to write properties as object is because if I have to go back and add stuff to them I don't have to change anything. my code segment is shown below:

```
const MovieSchema = new Schema({
    title : {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    category : {
        type : String      
    },
    country : {
        type : String        
    },
    year : {
        type : Number
    },
    imdbScore : {
        type : Number
    },
    directorId : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
})
```

The thing making me worry is does doing this making my code slower, it wont matter in my learning project but I don't want to get used to it for future projects.

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Thanks for the article @VLAZ , I'll keep that in my mind for future references.

Just the clarify you are saying that it doesn't matter, right? because the article also mentions performance is dependent on many things, only you can answer this question truly etc. but I don't think those parts don't really apply here.

Comment: I don't see *how* performance matters here. You have an object literal. JS is quite optimised for using those. So, the object literal is unlikely to have a problem. `Schema` presumably reads and does stuff with that but it'd be *once*. It's quite hard to say if something is "slow" if *you* don't know if it is. And it's also usually not worth prematurely optimising. We get questions all the time about trying to "optimise" stuff that really doesn't matter without the code ever having been a problem nor any performance measures been taken.

Comment: Thanks, I had some comments on my code on other languages like "Don't write this like X it slows down your program" etc. so I didn't want to same mistakes learning Node.js

Comment: It's certainly possible to do things slow in node, just like any other language,  C++ / Rust etc etc.  Without knowing how this Schema is used, it's hard to say if this is sub-optimal or not.  Another idea though, depending on why your using a Schema, Typescript is a zero cost runtime, for this sort of stuff,